# How to implement ENUM/SET in Peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I've done ok replacing the ENUM functionality in MariaDB with Peewee CHOICES:
https://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html

```
class Catalog(BaseModel):
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0,'New'),
        (1,'Processing'),
        (2,'Installed'))
    status = CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Status', choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='New', constraints=[SQL("DEFAULT 'New'")])
```

However, I'm stuck on replacing the somewhat similar SET functionality:  https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-data-type/

Here is the field in SQL syntax:

```
   `Ports` set('443','587','636','990','993','995','1054','3128','3129','3306','5432','6697','8000','8443','9443','61617') NOT NULL DEFAULT '443',
```

The data can look like this, basically a multi-select field with a limited set of options:

```
+---------------+
| Ports         |
+---------------+
| 443           |
| 8443          |
| 443,9443      |
| 3306          |
| 443,3128,8000 |
| 587           |
+---------------+
```

Trying to avoid using a separate table to hold this data, if possible.

Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the first option is to subclass and create a custom field for the set type. I'm not sure how this works since I've never used this functionality in MariaDB - but it should be possible. Docs: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#creating-a-custom-field

You might try Peewee's built-in `BitField` which uses an integer (typically 64-bits) so you can use a bit-mask to effectively represent a set of 64 values -- incidentally I would guess this is what MariaDB is doing behind-the-scenes. Docs for this here: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#bitfield-and-bigbitfield